# Visual Workflow

Tags: visual-workflow

I want to learn about visual workflows, but I am kind of stuck. I wonder if it is possible to update a field of another object. For example:

```
Object1
StartTime__c
source__c : lookup to Object2

Object2
StartTime__c
```

When `StartTime__c` is updated on `Object2`, I want to update `StartTime__c` on `Object1`. Is it possible to do that with visual workflows, and how would I get started?
Tia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By 'object' do you actually mean record? Given that your use case is that a specific parameter 'time' is updated, I'm going to presume that's what you mean.

In which case, yes, it's very possible for flow to do this, but there are several ways to implement based on how the object to be updated should be selected.

However, it's important to understand that Flow is best used as a *user initiated action* - it's typically a custom button or tab which calls the flow. In  your example, it would typically be a workflow action or trigger which would best suit firing on a date change. The new Process Builder is the best fit for your case - it's like flow but designed to handle record updates based on events.

Regardless, here is a broad guide to the principles:

1. Flows rely on the passing of variables - input and output variables - to populate the flow and to pass out results of the flow.
2. You can pull in any aspect of a source record (like the start date) by setting up a variable to hold the value and using a custom URL to pass the variables through (like this: /flow/Your_Flow?vRecordTypeID={!YourObject.RecordTypeID})
3. You need a way to identify the target record for the update though - is it fixed? Is it related to the first record? Depending on how complex this element of your use case is, you may have to go to greater lengths to pass in the Id of the target record to be changed as a result of the flow.
4. Finally, you have to give some thought to the process of activating such a flow. Ideally, you have a special button to perform the update to the date field which then also updates the other record as part of the same flow. However, you can also use 'headless flows' (flows without a data entry screen) if you're in the pilot, which can be activated by workflow. If you're not in the pilot, you'll need to look at Process Builder instead, as that is now replacing headless flow workflow actions as the preferred solution from Salesforce.